# Associative Container as Function Template Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl, metaprogramming

I would like to know how I would write a function that can accept as a parameter an associative container that itself accepts two or more template parameters. For example, if I want to write a function that works for std::map, I could write something like what is shown below.

```
template <class Map, class Key, class Value, class Compare, class Allocator>
void foo(Map<Key, Value, Compare, Allocator>& map);
```

However, this will not work for boost::unordered_map, since boost::unordered_map accepts five template parameters. I could accept the map as a single template parameter and use the traits that it should support in order to deduce the key and value types later, but for nested maps, the code becomes very verbose and difficult to maintain. Is there an easier way to write such a function but still have it work for any associative container that accepts any number of template parameters greater than or equal to two?

Please note that accepting iterators instead of containers as parameters will not suffice, because I need more information about the container on which the iterator operates than what the iterator can provide.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the simple approach with a single template parameter:

```
template <typename C> void foo(const C & container)
{
  typedef typename C::key_type key_type;
  typedef typename C::mapped_type mapped_type;

  // etc.
}
```

You can add some member-type-checking typetraits is you want additional checks that those member types exist, but that might not give any additional benefit.

Alternatively, you could do some generic pattern matching, though only with classes, not functions:

```
 template <typename> struct AtLeastTwo;

 template <typename K, typename V, typename ...Args>
 struct AtLeastTo<K, V, Args...>
 {
   // now have types K and V
 };
```

```
 typedef std::unordered_map<int, Foo, MyHash> map_type;
 AtLeastTwo<map_type> m;
 // ...
```

Comment: The code becomes very verbose for nested maps, especially if the inner map is of a different type than the outer map. Extracting all of the correct types involves a great deal of type manipulation using Boost.TypeTraits. I just wanted to know whether there's an easier way to do this without using traits to introspect values, but I suppose not.

Comment: What exactly are the complications that nested maps add? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve; by the looks at it, it shouldn't matter if any of the involved types are themselves maps.

Comment: Yes, but if I need iterators to the types in the outer and inner maps, regardless of their const-qualifications or whether they are pointers or references, I need to create utility classes with several overloaded methods just to accomplish some trivial tasks.

Comment: The initialization step of the for-loop alone takes over 30 characters because of the template parameters involved, and the code gets much worse when I have to do more complicated tasks.

Comment: Let's back up: What are you trying to *do*? I once wrote some code (here on SO I think) that'll recursively iterate everything that can possibly be iterated, and that only took a few lines of code.

Comment: For a particular project I need to use a three-way lookup map, so the outer key is used to access a map, at which point a second key is used to access a value. Various statistics are computed using these three-way lookup maps, so there's a lot of nested iteration.

Comment: So is it something like `map<K1, map<K2, V>>`, but templated on everything? You could still use the simple approach above and use `C::mapped_type::key_type` for `K2` and `C::mapped_type::mapped_type` for `V`...

Answer (score 0):

A type does not convey information on whether it is an associative sequence, such is a semantic meaning. If you wan't to support all kinds of associative sequence, as per the standard interface, your best bet is to go with a single template parameter and use traits to introspect its key/value type and so on.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but the boilerplate code to support nested maps using traits is several hundred lines long on its own, so I wanted to know if there's any easier way to go about this. After reading both answers, however, I suppose that there is no easier way.